# crystal report head title mess up

Tags: crystal-reports, report, head

I deploy a crystal report to customer server,but occur some wrong ,

my local computer the situation:

[image]

the result is correct

but In customer server

[image]

```
The head mess up ,I try the resolution ratio and browserVersion ,but it cannot reproduce it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this response on another site:

This is actually a Crystal Reports bug which affects **13.0.4** Version.
Iit **works fine when you run the same report using the 13.0.3** (and probably earlier) version.

This bug is known to the CR team and they are going to solve it: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3207181

[Look here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824), you can download actual and previous versions of runtime.